# Openlayers 3 apply style to a part of a feature which is overlapping another layer or feature

Tags: openlayers-3

How could one apply a style to the part of a feature which is overlapping another feature?

In essence what i would need is something like this picture.

[image]

Here the blue dotted style would be applied to the white line for the parts which are overlapping with the lighter blue feature.

Comment: You must create a new feature with a geometry with the same coordinates as the overlap. Then show it in an overlay layer. There is no functions, as far as I know, that can find the overlap. So you have to code it by your self.